# Есть ли уточнение и нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Прошу Вас(,) по счету №255 от 16.02.2016 г. для заказчика ПАО «Нижнекамскнефтехим»(,) рассмотреть возможность прикрепления листов комплектации на коробки со сборным товаром, в которых будут указаны артикулы и количество, и при дальнейшей отгрузке товара со склада «ОБО Беттерманн» в г. Крекшино МО, скоординировать действия сотрудников склада согласно нашей просьбе.

Answer (score 3):

Только те две, что выделяют оборот «в которых будут...», оставить. Остальные три — без причины стоят. «Артикула» следует заменить на «артикулы».

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужны. То же самое:

> Прошу Вас по этому поводу не беспокоиться.

И

> Прошу Вас по счету №255 произвести оплату.

**Обновления**

Я написал такие же по структуре предложения, но без навешанных второстепенных членов предложения, чтобы стало очевидно, что запятые не нужны.

> Прошу Вас по счету №255 произвести оплату.
>
> Прошу Вас по счету №255 от 16.02.2016 г. для заказчика ПАО «Нижнекамскнефтехим» рассмотреть возможность произведения оплаты.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?